# Using homebrew on mac instead of yum

Tags: ruby, homebrew, yum

I'm following some instructions of setting up my dev environment for a new job. They use ubuntu I'm assuming and I have a mac. would it be fine for me to use homebrew instead of yum that they are using? For example I need to execute the following on my mac but since mac doesn't come with yum, I'll need to stick with some other utility to install these libraries. Does anyone have experience replicating the below on mac?

```
sudo yum install -y libyaml-devel gcc ruby-devel libxml2 libxml2-devel libxslt libxslt-devel libcurl-devel  postgresql-devel zlib zlib-devel readline readline-devel sqlite-devel mod_ssl
```

Comment: 1) ubunut uses apt-get and not yum 2)yum  is  an  interactive, rpm based, package manager used by centos distro and its derivatives (e.g: redhat..etc).3) brew is a package manager for mac ... so you are comparing apples , oranges and tomatoes .. I use all three of them ... when on my mac , i use brew , yum when in redhat redhat .. bottom line is ...it is not a matter of choice between either or , instead they are utilities for doing different stuff.

Comment: Homebrew can install most of those libraries, but check with your employer first as to whether OS X is an acceptable dev environment at all. If not, you'll want to set up a VM with CentOS.